# Console log stack trace in firefox - version 54

Tags: firefox, firebug

How to make firefox display the entire stack trace in its console log.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox DevTools do show the file and the line and column numbers within the file where the error occurred.

[image: Error message in Firefox DevTools console]

On errors you can also expand the stack trace right within the console by clicking the little arrow besides the error message.

See the [related documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#JS) for more info about that.

Firebug also [shows this information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921610/432681) in its console:

[image: Error message in Firebug console]

In there you can also display the stack trace by clicking the + icon besides the message.

*Note: [Firebug is discontinued in favor of the Firefox DevTools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).*

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see the error, warning, etc on my console. Not sure how they were unchecked, but when I recheck the options, everything seems working.

[image]